# Mozilla developer page - But never use this form

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, mozilla, ecmascript-5, typeof

My question is about the Mozilla developer page: [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof)

In the example chapter, whenever a comparison of the following form is done they comment it:

```
typeof Number(1) === 'number'; // but never use this form!
```

Although they never explain why. It's easy to see why it's a silly way of going about type-checking, but I'm curious as to the reason why they went out of their way to make that comment multiple times.

Any clues are welcome.

**Note**: Is it because Number() is a constructor called without the new operator? (my first guess)

Ps: Code examples were tested in Firefox's console version 27.0

Comment: It’s definitely not because `Number` is used without `new`. You should *never* use primitive wrappers (which is what `Number` creates as a constructor).

Comment: @minitech also just curious, what's your way to typecast in JavaScript if you don't use that?

Comment: @Markasoftware: `Number(x)` is fine to cast. `new Number(x)` neither casts to number nor is fine.

Comment: @false: Technically, using `new` will still cast it (try `+new Number(8)`), it'll just be as a Number instance rather than the primitive type.

Comment: @rvighne: Sorry, what I meant was that it (`new Number`) is not a cast to a number. You’re right that it would cast anything before creating a `Number` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the lack of `new`. Writing `new Number(1)` creates a Number object with the value 1. This is seldom needed. However, `Number(1)` *does not* create a Number object — instead, it just returns the number 1. This is confusing (since it visually *looks* like object creation) and unnecessary since you can just write `1` instead.

Comment: While reviewing the submitted answers after all this time, yours makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

They *do* explain why. On that same page, (a little bit past what you copied), it says

```
typeof new Boolean(true) === 'object'; // this is confusing. Don't use!
typeof new Number(1) === 'object'; // this is confusing. Don't use!
typeof new String("abc") === 'object';  // this is confusing. Don't use!
```

Notice how the `new` keyword is there. In your example, there is no `new` keyword. Kind of hard to spot, isn't it? So what they're trying to say is that since one's type is `number` and the other's type is `object` but the two look so similar, it's can be confusing what you mean.

Many problems can arise from thinking an object is a number because it acts like a number in some ways. For example, type checking with `typeof` and comparisons with `===`.

Although, I can see that it isn't expressed very clearly on that page.

Comment: I see the point you're getting at, and I had considered it myself. But it doesn't make sense because both statements are semantically different: one is obviously intended as casting and the other seems like a way too slick hack to do casting - which is why it is confusing. I appreciate the feedback, but it doesn't quite ring true. :)

Comment: @KemHeyndels: They both do *essentially* the same thing. They convert the argument into a Number or Boolean or whatever. However, they just return it differently (one is a real primitive as expected, the other is an instance). This can be confusing to no end, and it's tough to catch for newbies who just see it in bad examples or use `new` because `Number` and friends are capitalized (look like a class). That's how I see it (and I speak from experience), sorry if it doesn't satisfy.

Comment: You're right about the example code in your post. It is confusing for the reasons you mentioned. The thing I'm trying to get at is why they said to never use the form of the example code in my post. I doubt it's for the same reason as the example you discussed. Like I said in the proposed answer, I think it's because javascript can cast any value to a value of the same type, which makes the type-check unnecessary. Your example will always yield object, which is not the underlying type we want to get -> confusing idd. ps: there are many mistakes noobs and adepts can make in js ;)

Answer (score 1):

The author(s) of that page seem to be a bit confused or intent on causing confusion.

There’s nothing wrong with that “form” except that `Number(1)` is redundant – it’s equivalent to `1`.

Arguably, it’s confusable with `new Number(x)`, but `+x` (the other common way) is kind of obscure at first glance, and there’s no chance of mixing the two up if you know to never use primitive wrappers.

Did I mention you should never use primitive wrappers?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Your last comment gave me a hint as to why they commented it. I'll see if I can update my post.